# X Ubuntu bluetooth audio sync not working

Tags: bluetooth, logitech

I have Xubuntu 13.10 and I cannot make my Logitech Bluetooth Audio Adapter work.

I get this message:

```
Connection Failed: Stream setup failed
```

For the moment, the light on device is green but after one second becomes red again.

I have tried several tutorials from various forums but without any luck.

Is there anything that works for sure?

Thanks for interest

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem connecting via bluetooth to a Sony soundbar on xubuntu 14.10 as well. I solved it by installing the pulseaudio bluetooth module:

```
# Install Module
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth

# Kill Pulseaudio (it'll auto-restart)
pulseaudio -k
```